# pyspark: how to apply udf to a particular node?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I apply UDF to the tags array (root>bankAccounts>transactions>tags) base in the following dataframe?

data_df.printSchema():

```
root
|-- reference: string (nullable = true)
|-- bankAccounts: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- accountName: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- currentBalance: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- transactions: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- amount: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- balance: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- tags: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- category: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- creditDebit: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- thirdParty: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
|-- countryCode: string (nullable = true)
|-- text: string (nullable = true)
```

The python method:

```
def transform_array_to_dict(tag):
    dall = {}
    for d in tag:
        for a in list(d.keys()):
            dall[a] = d[a]
    return dall
```

which change the outcome for each transaction tag from something like:

```
[
    {
        "category": "Dishonours"
    },
    {
        "creditDebit": "debit"
    }
]
```

into:

```
{
    "category": "Dishonours",
    "creditDebit": "debit"
}
```

The method run as intended, when I test

```
sample = transform_array_to_dict([{"category": "Dishonours"},{"creditDebit": "debit"}])
sample
```

My outcome is

```
{'category': 'Dishonours', 'creditDebit': 'debit'}
```

Comment: The schema suggests that the data is already in your desired format. Why are you still trying to convert?

Comment: @mck no it's not, the tags is an array of objects, I want to change it to just a key value object, I post in the question how the tags comes and I also add in the question the desire object and the python method, the main reason I'm doing this is that when I go to Athena I have an undesire outcome that happens because the tags is an array and not an object